# Investigating if $f_{xy}$ =$f_{yx}$ for $f(x,y)=\frac {2x-y}{x+y}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: partial-derivative

I have to verify that $$f(x,y)=\frac {2x-y}{x+y}$$
indicating possible exceptional points and intestigating those points
My attempt:

I calculated

$$f_x=\frac {3y}{(x+y)^2}$$
$$f_y=\frac {-3x}{(x+y)^2}$$
and for $$(x,y)\ne(0,0)$$
$$f_{xy}=\frac {3x-3y}{(x+y)^3}$$
$$f_{yx}=\frac {3x-3y}{(x+y)^3}$$
At $(0,0)$,does $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist?
My guess is that it does't exist because $f$ is not defined at $(0,0)$.Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, this makes no sense to speak further about derivatives when $f(0,0)$ is not even defined.  In this case $f(x,0)=2$ and $f(0,y)=-1$ so $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They indeed do not exist at $(0, 0)$ because of dividing by 0 (so there's a perforation at each set for which $x + y = 0$ is true). However, because at $(0, 0)$ $x = y$, $f_{x,y} \iff f_{y,x}$, so they are interchangeable, so i.e. their limits will be the same. They get very close to each other, intersecting when approaching 0, but they do not intersect at $(0, 0)$ because then $x + y = 0$ is true, which means the function won't exist at all.